# AWS authorizer returns 500, message: null, with AuthorizerConfigurationException error in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda-authorizer, aws-jwt-authorizer

I've spent the better part of today trying to make authorizers work, I've checked multiple examples and they all seem to be doing the same thing my code does.

I use serverless framework here's the authorization code:

```
exports.handler = function (event: APIGatewayTokenAuthorizerEvent): APIGatewayAuthorizerResult {
    const authorizer = new Authorizer();

    try {
        if (!event.authorizationToken) throw new Error("No token");

        const token = event.authorizationToken.split(" ")[1];
        const decodedData = authorizer.verifyToken(token) as unknown as User;
        const policy = generatePolicy(token, event.methodArn);

        return {
            ...policy,
            context: {
                user: JSON.stringify(decodedData),
            },
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw "Unauthorized";
    }
};

const generatePolicy = (principalId: string, methodArn: string) => {
    return {
        principalId,
        policyDocument: {
            Version: "2012-10-17",
            Statement: [
                {
                    Action: "execute-api:Invoke",
                    Effect: "Allow",
                    Resource: methodArn,
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

and here's the serverless config

```
const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
service: "user-crud",
frameworkVersion: "2",
custom: {
    webpack: {
        webpackConfig: "./webpack.config.js",
        includeModules: true,
    },
},
plugins: ["serverless-webpack"],
provider: {
    name: "aws",
    runtime: "nodejs14.x",
    region: "eu-west-1",
    apiGateway: {
        minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
        shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
        AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
    },
    lambdaHashingVersion: "20201221",
},

functions: {
    jwtAuthorizer: {
        handler: "src/api/authorizer.handler",
        name: "jwtAuthorizer",
    },
    get: {
        name: "get",
        handler: "src/api/get.handler",
        role: "arn:aws:iam::109394173706:role/dynamodb_cloudwatch_full",
        events: [
            {
                http: {
                    path: "get",
                    method: "get",
                    cors: true,
                    authorizer: "jwtAuthorizer",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

}...

I always get 500 response when the token is correct and I return the object, so I guess there's something wrong with the return object?

If the token is incorrect and I throw "Unauthorized" then I get back the correct 401 response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the handler needs to be async, otherwise, it expects a callback... Time well spent :|

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are some other reasons for getting,

```
{
    message : null
}
```

error from Api Gateway. I had a very hard time identifying mine.

1. The API Gateway might lack permission to invoke the authorizer lambda. Make sure you add `Lambda Invoke Role` for your authorizer
2. You should not modify the **request context** *(not talking about response context)*. Whenever I try, I get `Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: Unrecognized field "headers", not marked as ignorable` in Api Gateway Logs. You have to tackle it by adding **cors** with explicit mention of those headers
3. The return policy should comply with the Lambda response 1.0 version. If you want to use `boolean` based return, you must enable lambda response 2.0
4. If you have updated the authorizer lambda function name or something, it is better to `delete` the `RestApiGateway` and create again. The changes might not get updated in CloudFront properly sometimes.
5. The response context you give will allow only String, Number or Boolean types. Example,

```js
    function allowPolicy(methodArn) {
        console.log("Allow Policy")
        return {
            "principalId": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
            "policyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": methodArn
                    }
                ]
            },
            "context": {
                "stringValue": "blablabla",
                "numberValue": 10,
                "booleanValue": true,
            }
        };
    }
```